# How do I select the rows that have the same column entry as a row in a different data frame, as well as within an age range?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames. I want to select all rows in one dataframe where a particular column is equal to a column in a different data frame, as well as being inside 5 years older or younger than their age.

I have two dataframes, df:

```
Name    Gender   Age
John    Male     20
Joe     Male     23
Sarah   Female   34
Tim     Male     41
Amy     Female   22
```

and df1:

```
Name    Gender   Age
Tom     Male     24
```

I want to create a new data frame that displays the rows of df that have the same gender as df1, so basically have a data frame where the gender for all rows is male in this case. I want to avoid saying gender = male however. Then, these people also have to be within five years of Tom, so between 19 and 29. The output should be like so.

```
Name    Gender   Age
John    Male     20
Joe     Male     23
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What should happen when df1 has more than one entry?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use `df[df['Gender'].isin(df1['Gender'])]`

Comment: Thanks @jezrael that's perfect

Comment: Just as a follow up, if I had an age column for both data frames, How could I find the rows in df that are less than five years older and five years younger than Tom ?